# Remove array title from json

Tags: arrays, json

I have this array and I need to remove this parts.. I think about rebuild the json without this array or replace, but if have some easy form..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a lot of way to do this... One but not the best is create a new object receiving this jsonvariable.statusPropostas[0]
like this

```
newVariable = jsonvariable.statusPropostas[0]
```

and then create other object to ur full new body

```
const newObjectBody = {
descricaoStatusProposta = newVariable.descricaoStatusProposta
dataStatusPropostaDate = newVariable.dataStatusPropostaDate
dataStatusProposta  = newVariable.dataStatusProposta
codigoStatusProposta = newVariable.codigoStatusProposta

numeroProposta = jsonvariable.numeroProposta
numeroMerchant = jsonvariable.numeroMerchant  
indicadorEcommerce = jsonvariable.indicadorEcommerce 
descricaoMotivoRejeicao = jsonvariable.descricaoMotivoRejeicao 
DataPropostaDate = jsonvariable.DataPropostaDate 
dataProposta = jsonvariable.dataProposta 
}
```